# How parse arrays of items in array to float/int

Tags: javascript, arrays

How I parse array of arrays to float/int?

I have:

```
0: Array [ "2011", "127072,7" ]
1: Array [ "2012", "125920,3" ]
2: Array [ "2013", "129305,4" ]
3: Array [ "2014", "135364" ]
4: Array [ "2015", "136757" ]
5: Array [ "2016", "155653,5" ]
6: Array [ "2017", "164130,5" ]
```

And i need converted to

```
[[2011, 127072.7], [2012, 125920.3], [2013, 129305.4], [2014, 135364], ..... ]
```

So next thing is a replace `,` with `.`.

Is there some solution for this?

Comment: What have you tried? You're expected to at least try then come back if you have issues. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `map` method with `Number` constructor.

```
let result = array.map(arr => arr.map(item => Number(item.replace(/,/g, '.'))))
```

```js
let array = [[ "2011", "127072,7" ], [ "2012", "125920,3" ]]
console.log(array.map(arr => arr.map(item => Number(item.replace(/,/g, '.')))));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have more than one deep level, recursive solution also could helps

```js
const arrays = [
  [
    "2017", 
    [
      "2014",
      [ "2017", "164130,5" ]
     ],
  ],
  [ "2011", "127072,7" ],
  [ "2012", "125920,3" ],
  [ "2013", "129305,4" ],
  [ "2014", "135364" ],
  [ "2015", "136757" ],
  [ "2016", "155653,5" ],
  [ "2017", "164130,5" ],
]

function formatNumber(string) {
  return +string.replace(`,`, `.`)
}

function recursiveSolution(array) {
  return array.map(item => typeof item === "string" ? formatNumber(item) : recursiveSolution(item))
}

const result = recursiveSolution(arrays)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this :

```
var result = array.map(function(arr){

   return arr.map(function(num){
      return Number(num.replace(',' , '.'))
   })

})
```

Comment: This is not working because `"127072,7"` is converted to `NaN`.

Comment: Yes, i fixed it now.